# How can I set a path to setup.cfg in vs-code for its python plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-python

I have a development directory in which a python package is kept as a sub-directory.
The package itself does not ship a *setup.cfg*, however, I like to have some development related settings which I do not want to push to the package, therefore I keep a *setup.cfg* file in the development directory.

E.g.

```
|- devdir/  # remote container -> /workspaces/devdir
   |- .devcontainer/
   |- setup.cfg
   |- package/
      |- package/
         |- __init__.py
         |- ...
```

My goal is to use the remote development within a docker container available for VS-Code.

## Problem

VS-Code however, does not see the *setup.cfg* file and keeps showing errors for linters etc which would generally be handled by settings within *setup.cfg*.

## Question

Is there a way to tell VS-Code where to look for the *setup.cfg* and provide that information to the python and remote plugins?

Answer (score 3):

Add the entry `python.linting.pylintArgs: ["--rcfile=setup.cfg"]` to your `.vscode/settings.json` file in your project folder.

Comment: Just make sure that you've enabled the configuration for the right plugin. Multiple plugins may use the same setup.cfg, but will need to be configured separately. For me, this was: ```"python.linting.flake8Args": ["--rcfile=setup.cfg"]``` in my .vscode > settings.json file.

Comment: Related to @ADataGMan's comment, if you're using the flake8 vs code extension, you need to use `"flake8.args": [ "--config", "<PATH>" ]`